# babel-preset-env not recognizing jsx

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I'm trying to do a webpack build for the first time and I have looked over my babel config a bunch of times relative to the docs but I cannot for the life of me see where it's wrong.  All the same I am getting an error on build of a pretty simple app (almost the default app, with redux hooked up):

```
ERROR in ./src/index.js
Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token (10:2)
   8 | 
   9 | ReactDOM.render(
> 10 |   <Provider store={store}>
     |   ^
  11 |     <App />
  12 |   </Provider>, global.document.getElementById('root'));
  13 | registerServiceWorker();
```

Here is my `webpack.config.js`:

```
const path = require('path');
const UglifyJSPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  plugins: [
    new UglifyJSPlugin()
  ],
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          'css-loader'
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif)$/,
        use: [
          'file-loader'
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules)/,
        use: [
          'babel-loader'
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

also Ive used a variation suggested by the webpack docs:

```
{
  test: /\.js$/,
  exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
  use: {
    loader: 'babel-loader',
    options: {
      presets: ['env']
    }
  }
}
```

and my `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "interactor",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      ["env", {
        "targets": {
          "browsers": ["last 2 versions"]
        }
      }]
    ]
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.0.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^0.31.3",
    "react-dom": "^16.0.0",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.6",
    "react-scripts": "1.0.14",
    "redux": "^3.7.2",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack --config webpack.config.js",
    "build": "webpack",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.0",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.7",
    "eslint": "^4.8.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^15.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.7.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^5.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.4.0",
    "file-loader": "^1.1.5",
    "style-loader": "^0.19.0",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^0.4.6",
    "webpack": "^3.6.0"
  }
}
```

and I guess index.js might be useful too:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import store from './store';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>, global.document.getElementById('root'));
registerServiceWorker();
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As usual, user error, but maybe it will help another newb like me down the line.  Just never put "react" into my babel presets.  It should have looked, e.g., like

```
"babel": {
    "presets": [
      "react",
      ["env", {
        "targets": {
          "browsers": ["last 2 versions"]
        }
      }]
    ]
  }
```

Oh, and make sure you actually have `babel-preset-react` installed.