# Set version of EcmaScript generated by Babel, in react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, babeljs, ecmascript-2017

I'm using the latest ES8 features in my react code, for example, async and await. Because of misconfiguration problem in my webpack config, I cannot use source maps, and this slows down debugging.

A quick solution could be to locally compile source code into ES7 or ES8, and test in the latest Chrome. How can I set this in `.babelrc`? Here's my current .babelrc:

```
{
  "presets": [
     "react-app"
  ] 
}
```

Comment: You should be using the env present and setting your targets.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-preset-env

Comment: You can set your target to a specific version of Chrome. The target would be something like Chrome >= 58. Preset env uses browserslist.

https://github.com/browserslist/browserslist#full-list

Comment: @SimeonSmith when I set .babelrc to `{
  "presets": [
    ["env", {
      "targets": {
        "chrome": 67
      }
    }]
  ]
}`, Babel cannot recognize jsx. So this is not enough

Comment: Don't remove the react-app preset.

`{ "presets": [ "react-app", ["env", { "targets": { "chrome": 67 } }] ] }`

Answer (score 0):

Answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46613828/babel-preset-env-not-recognizing-jsx),

```
{
  "presets": [
    "react",
    ["env", {
      "targets": {
        "chrome": 67
      }
    }]
  ]
}
```

As of Jul 2018, the above setting would not support [spread operator in objects](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-object-rest-spread). To enable it,

```
npm install --save-dev babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread
```

Use the following configuration in `.babelrc`:

```
{
  "presets": [
    "react",
    ["env", {
      "targets": {
        "chrome": 67
      }
    }]
  ],
  "plugins": ["transform-object-rest-spread"]
}
```